# [BotFramework][Cortana] How does a user send Attachments to the Bot within Cortana?

Tags: c#, attachment, cortana

I created a Chatbot (Microsoft Botframework) with a Cortana Skill where i am trying to prompt the user to upload an attachment.

The prompt is asking the user to upload the file as specified (Code below) but i do not see a possibility of uploading files in Cortana. Is there a way to make this work? Thanks a lot!

```
    var dialog = new PromptDialog.PromptAttachment("Please upload the sick 
    note you received from your doctor.", "Sorry, I didn't get the document. 
    Try again please.", 2);
    context.Call(dialog,this.uploadAttachmentResumeAfter);
```

Comment: My experience with Cortana skills is that they are rather limited. Have you tried to drag-and-drop the file?

Comment: I have not tried but I saw send/receive snippets on github. Do they work? Only thing you'd need to be careful about is deviceInfo and checking for a screen.

Answer (score 0):

The Cortana Skills Kit does not presently support file uploads through Cortana. However, you can work around this by [deep linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/launch-apps-from-skills) - add the capability to support a html form file upload in your app and follow the steps to invoke it in the mentioned doc.

Hope this helps.